# i am trying to create a incircle of a triangle circle has been created but it doesn't touches sides in every input i am giving

Tags: opengl

what is the reason i am not getting in-circle touching every side of triangle.is there any problem line drawing code ? some times i am getting circle most if the part outside triangle and sometime completely inside.
[image: below is sample output i am getting]

```
#include<GL/glut.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int w,h,a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l;

void Init()
{
        glClearColor(0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluOrtho2D(0,w,0,h);
}
int round1(double number)
{
        return (number>=0) ? (int)(number+0.5):(int)(number-0.5);
}
void setPixel(int x,int y)
{       
        glColor3f(0,1,1);                      
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        glEnd();
}
void LineWithDDA(int x0,int y0,int x1,int y1)
{
        int dy=y1-y0;
        int dx=x1-x0;
        int steps,i;
        float xinc,yinc,x=x0,y=y0;
        if(abs(dx)>abs(dy))
        {
                steps=abs(dx);
        }
        else
        {
                steps=abs(dy);
        }
        xinc=(float)dx/(float)steps;
        yinc=(float)dy/(float)steps;
        setPixel(round1(x),round1(y));
        for(i=0;i<steps;i++)
        {
                x+=xinc;
                y+=yinc;
                setPixel(round1(x),round1(y));
        }
        glutSwapBuffers();
}

circledim(int x1,int y1,int x2,int y2,int x3,int y3)
{
 float A,B,C,S,P,incX,incY,At;
 int R;

    A=  (float) sqrt((x2-x1)*(x2-x1)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
    B=  (float) sqrt((x3-x2)*(x3-x2)+(y2-y1)*(y2-y1));
    C=  (float) sqrt((x3-x1)*(x3-x1)+(y3-y1)*(y3-y1));

    S=  (float)(A+B+c)/2;

    At= (float) sqrt(S*(S-A)*(S-B)*(S-C));
        R=  (int) At/ (int)S;
    P=  A+B+C;

    incX=(int) (B*x1+C*x2+A*x3)/(int)P;
    incY=(int) (B*y1+C*y2+A*y3)/(int)P;

    int xCenter=incX,yCenter=incY,r=R;

        int x=0,y=r;
        int d=3/2-r;

        glColor3f(0,1,1);
        while(x<=y)
        {
                setPixel(xCenter+x,yCenter+y);
                setPixel(xCenter+y,yCenter+x);
                setPixel(xCenter-x,yCenter+y);
                setPixel(xCenter+y,yCenter-x);
                setPixel(xCenter-x,yCenter-y);
                setPixel(xCenter-y,yCenter-x);
                setPixel(xCenter+x,yCenter-y);
                setPixel(xCenter-y,yCenter+x);

                if(d<0)
                        d+=(2*x)+3;
                else
                {
                        d+=(2*(x-y))+5;
                        y-=1;
                }
                x++;
        }
        //glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();

 }

void Display()
{
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        LineWithDDA(a,b,c,d);
        LineWithDDA(c,d,e,f);
        LineWithDDA(e,f,a,b);
        circledim(a,b,c,d,e,f);
}
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
        glutInit(&argc,argv);
        glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE|GLUT_RGB);
        glutInitWindowPosition(0,0);
        printf("Enter the details:\n");
        printf("Windows width w : ");
        scanf("%d",&w);
        printf("Windows heigth h : ");
        scanf("%d",&h);
        glutInitWindowSize(w,h);


        printf("\nInitial Vertex : x1: ");       
        scanf("%d",&a);
        printf(" y1: ");
        scanf("%d",&b);
        printf("\nsecond Vertex : x2: ");
        scanf("%d",&c);
        printf(" y2: ");
        scanf("%d",&d); 


        printf("\nthird Vertex : x3: ");
        scanf("%d",&e);
        printf(" y3: ");
        scanf("%d",&f);
        glutDisplayFunc(Display);

        glutCreateWindow("dda Line");
        glutDisplayFunc(Display);  
        Init();
        glutMainLoop(); 
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you wrote your own line drawing routine instead of using `GL_LINES`? Also, why don't you print out the center and radius of the circle to the console so you can see if it's giving you the correct value. Then you can determine if the problem is with your math, or with your drawing.

Comment: I think he also draws the circle with his own function... Assignment?

Comment: i have just started opengl. i want to be more clear regarding line drawing circle drawing algorithms.thats why i am using these algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than attack your phalanx of variables, I'll post the method for generating an inscribed circle.

Inscribed circle:

1. Find the **incenter** of the circle. This is the point where the three rays bisecting the triangle's angles meet. I'd post the formula for the incenter, but it's nicely formatted [here on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incircle_and_excircles_of_a_triangle#Coordinates_of_the_incenter) and is easy to figure out. Solve it by yourself to check that your formula's working properly.
2. The area of the triangle is `sr`, where `s=(a+b+c)/2`, and `r` is the radius of the incircle. A little algebra will help you find the radius.

Also, things to note:

- Your line for `S` reads `S=  (float)(A+B+c)/2;` and something tells me you might want to capitalize that `c`.